# Event Listings Data Model

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm working on an app which I will be displaying events (sporting events, concerts, etc, etc). I'm trying to come up with a model where I can single out teams playing for sporting events, and bands/artists playing in a concert.

My initial stab at is it to have an events table, team table, band/artist table. But I can't figure out the optimal way of handling the two teams or the many band/artists performing at an event.

Is it ok to have multiple fields NULL if they do not apply to the record? I always thought it's best to limit the amount of NULL fields in a record.

Comment: What is the data difference between `team` and `band` or any other type of `person/thing` an `event` is based around? Do they have different data associated with them or are they just different types of things?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to attack this.

You'll certainly have an events table.

Whether you split sports teams and bands into separate tables will depend on what information you're maintaining about each and how you feel about the NULLS. My understanding is that there is virtually no performance hit by having nulls in your records (I'm sure it varies by database) -- the real downside is potentially an unwieldy table if you have a lot of sports- and music-related fields all mixed in together.

If you do create separate sports and concert tables, you'll need to consider how you'll handle the "etc, etc" from your question. Into which table will magicians and sword-swallowers go?

As for connecting multiple teams/acts with an event, I'd be inclined to create an intermediate table to perform that linking. Each record would reference an event id and a performer id. You could have one record for an event (one performer) or two records for a sporting event (two teams) or n records for a many-act concert.

Then to pull up the show bill, you'll look up your event, and then use the intermediate table to find all the acts appearing at that event, and use those ids to get the name and details for each act.

Comment: I think I'm trying to hard to find the best way. Wish I could take a look at how some of the ticket companies handle it. They obviously have their databases modeled correctly. 

I think I'm going to lean towards having a larger table and just deal with having some NULLs and o some testings of if its sports, concert or theater.

Comment: IF the ticket companies are handling it correctly now (and it is amazing how many big companies do it badly), be assured that they did it badly in the past, probably for many years and through second, third, and fourth tries. You're already ahead, but at some point we just have to accept that each new domain is a learning experience and there are going to be refactorings ahead. Plan and budget accordingly, and devote more energy to results in the early iterations because early is the easiest time to refactor.

Comment: ...Also, worry less now about the data schema and more about putting an API/service layer between your domain/business logic and that database. As long as you get that done right, you can refactor the database to your heart's content without breaking the client code (i.e. after you've given something that actually works to the people paying the bills -- they don't care about your schema).